# How to access anaconda-navigator from Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: anaconda, virtual-machine, ubuntu-19.04

I am unable to access anaconda-navigator from Ubuntu 19.10. I have searched Google for the solution but still I am getting the following error:

[image]

Please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:

$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
$ anaconda-navigator